# Cannot access state of vuex module

Tags: vue.js, module, state, vuex, quasar

This is my first project with Vue and I am having some trouble accessing state of vuex module.
I am currently using quasar.

Here is my code calling the state.

```
    mounted() {
    console.log("Connected", this.$store.hasModule("module"));
    console.log("Module: ", this.$store.state.module);
    console.log("State: ", this.$store.state.module.count)
    console.log("Map State: ", this.count);
  },
  computed: {
    // look up in `some/nested/module`
    ...mapState({
      count: state => state.module.count // Uses the state of the module
    })
  },
```

And here is the output I am getting

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioRr1.png)

```
Connected true
OverviewPage.vue?1b50:26 Module:  Object
OverviewPage.vue?1b50:27 State:  undefined
OverviewPage.vue?1b50:28 Map State:  undefined
```

Here are my vuex codes.
This is index of the base vuex(where vuex is put).

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

// import example from './module-example'

Vue.use(Vuex);

/*
 * If not building with SSR mode, you can
 * directly export the Store instantiation;
 *
 * The function below can be async too; either use
 * async/await or return a Promise which resolves
 * with the Store instance.
 */

export default function(/* { ssrContext } */) {
  const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      module: () => import("src/store/module-example/index.js")
    },

    // enable strict mode (adds overhead!)
    // for dev mode only
    strict: process.env.DEBUGGING
  });

  return Store;
}
```

This is the index inside my 'module' folder

```
import state from "./state";
import * as getters from "./getters";
import * as mutations from "./mutations";
import * as actions from "./actions";

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions,
  state
};
```

And this is my state file inside that module.

```
export default function() {
  return {
    count: 0
  };
}
```

I have never used vuex before so, I am not really sure where I am getting this wrong.
If you have any solutions or advices for this, I would very much appreciate it! :)
Thanks ahead!

Comment: Hi, Define your state file as: `export default state { count: 0 }`

Comment: Thanks but it still returns undefined :(

Comment: Since you are new to Vuex, I suggest simplifying your store by removing the module and putting state, mutations, etc. directly in your Vuex.Store.  Then when you get it working, you can move some functionality back into a module.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that will be a good idea for me start. Thanks for the advice!
But I still don't get why I cannot access the state when everything seems to be right :(